# In Prettyphoto.js or Fancybox... How to add a link within the caption

Tags: jquery, fancybox, shadowbox

Help! I'm working on a website for a team of writers.

They want to show examples of specific jobs they've worked on (portfolio) by using the shadowbox effect.

Once opened (in overlay) the picture which is actually a screenshot of a .doc for instance, would have a caption to explain it roughly. The thing is, they want a link inside the caption so the user can download the files (.doc, .pdf) to their desktop or link to another site that they haved worked on.

I've managed to do it with Fancybox but the way the link is included in the  it shows  undesirable text when hovered (the browser yellow tooltip).

Here is the code:

```
<a class="group" rel="portfolio"
 href="../../images/pf_nat/cfcBig.png" title="Rédaction de plus de 300 articles. <a href='http://www.groupecfc.com/fr-Ca/' target='_blank'>Visiter le site</a>"><img src="../../images/pf_nat/tn_nat_cfcBig.gif" alt="" width="40" height="40"/></a>
```

in this case it's a link to some site.

Comment: Ok to do this i used Prettyphoto.js (great Montreal guy plugin), and use the ALT attribute for caption and insert html inside the ALT using entities for hyperlinks that's it, it works and it's valid! you can now use the title attribute for the right purpose (tooltips will show normaly without brackets and code etc.)for i don't use the title at all hehe. Thank you Matt and Scott a the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's like most 'lightbox' plugins, I believe you need to do this use character entities for example:

`<a href="test.html">hello</a>`

would become

`&lt;a href=&quot;text.html&quot;&gt;hello&lt;/a&gt;`

Put this in your title tag and it will link.

Get a full list of HTML character entities at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: should i put the entities on the outside A tags or on the inside?

Comment: Hey Scott i have inserted the converted html... it still works. so i guess my main Bug would be to hide the tooltips (right now its shows the title and everything like html tags within the title. sorry if i make you guys waste your time :(

Comment: If you put the converted code into another attribute (class, for example) and look it up from there, that will do the job of getting rid of your tooltips. Perhaps add: 'title': this.class, to your options. It's not the way it was meant to work, though. It's a built-in-to-browser thing, the tooltips.

Comment: Dang. Thanks you Scott (and Matt) i think i'll find another way to "show preview " of some work and make it available for download... I'll try to find a gallery that can handle can handle links inside the caption.

Comment: But if your URL is test.html?a=1&b=2 then it breaks when you try to add &amp; into the URL. ANY SOLUTION??

Answer (score 4):

Thanks so much for this post!  It helped me greatly, but then the tooltip showing up blew it all out of the water for me.  THEN! I found an easy fix to that part also. Add a title attribute that contains a space (must have a space) to the img inside the anchor tag:

```
    <a title="&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.mysite.com&quot; title=&quot;&quot;   target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;http://www.mysite.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt; " rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://www.mysite.com/wm/wp-content/themes/site/images/portfolio/image.jpg" style=""><img alt="Interactive" **title=" "** src="http://www.mysite.com/wm/wp-content/themes/site/images/portfolio/image.jpg"></a>
```

Wahoo!  No Tooltip and the caption works with a link added.

Answer (score 2):

This topic of PrettyPhoto and the inability to add a photo download link
has been a discussion for a couple of years now.  I'm amazed that the original
authors have not addressed this ... as far as I know.

There are now several versions of PrettyPhoto, including some mash-ups that
are used as plugins for Joomla, WordPress, etc.

So I took the Joomla plugin and modified it.  It can run stand-alone, without
Joomla (as I don't use Joomla).  You can see my modification here:
http://www.catpin.com/prettyphoto

I also include two zipped files:
1) the actual jquery.prettyPhoto.js file
2) the PHP script that does the download (opens the browser download dialog box).

I hope this helps out ... or at least gives you an idea that it can be done.