# Links within caption on Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox 2 to generate a gallery. As well as text, I'd like to have links in the captions of my photos, if necessary.

Here's the page where I'd like to have links within the captions: http://catjohnson.co.uk/weddings

By simply adding an html link in there (following this answer: [In Prettyphoto.js or Fancybox... How to add a link within the caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876640/in-prettyphoto-js-or-fancybox-how-to-add-a-link-within-the-caption)) it breaks the photo within the gallery.

I've tried following this http://jsfiddle.net/FWTZA/ and although it works, I lose my styling.

I can't seem to get my styling to integrate with the js fiddle code… Here's what I'm doing at the minute, which is working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        nextEffect  : 'fade',
        prevEffect  : 'fade',
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background-color' : '#eee'
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});
```

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks for taking a look!

Martin :)

Comment: what do you mean with "you lose your styling"? does this mean the link or the whole title?

Comment: Hi @jfk, It doesn't work with the 'helpers' commands. The #eee background overlay and the 'inside' command, which makes the caption appear inside the photo's border, like a polaroid picture, break the code.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/FWTZA/372/ with the helpers included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this html

```
<a class="fancybox" data-title-id="title-1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<div id="title-1" class="hidden">
    This is 1st title. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
</div>

<a class="fancybox" data-title-id="title-2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<div id="title-2" class="hidden">
    This is <b>2nd title</b>. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
</div>​
```

...set the helpers option and don't forget to separate each option with a comma like :

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        nextEffect  : 'fade',
        prevEffect  : 'fade',
        helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background-color' : '#eee'
                    }
                }
            },
        beforeLoad: function() {
            var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');
            if (id) {
                el = $('#' + id);

                if (el.length) {
                    this.title = el.html();
                }
            }
        }
    });​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FWTZA/372

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we did it, pulling all images and urls out of a database:

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
 $.fancybox(
  [ 
   { href : '/images/gallery_pic.php?id=229', title: 'Sample image one', rel : 'fancybox-thumb', class : 'fancybox-thumb'},
   { href : '/images/gallery_pic.php?id=167', title: ' Sample image two <a href="http://www.address" target="_blank">See site</a>', rel : 'fancybox-thumb', class : 'fancybox-thumb'}
  ],
  {
   type : 'image',
   autoScale : true,
   prevEffect : 'none',
   nextEffect : 'none',
   helpers : {
    title   : {
        type: 'inside',
        position: 'top'
    },

   } // closes helpers
  }               
 );
});
```

Comment: looks like a helper is missing (or the comma should not be there)