# Using a caption and fading images in FancyBox2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using a caption for a title in FancyBox 2. I grabbed the code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/

```
$(".fancybox")  
.attr('rel', 'gallery')  
.fancybox({  
beforeLoad: function() {  
this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');  
}  
});
```

It works fine. I want to change the image transitions from elastic to fade.
Code taken from here: [Links within caption on Fancybox 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725443/links-within-caption-on-fancybox-2).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({  
    openEffect  : 'fade',  
    closeEffect : 'fade',  
    nextEffect  : 'fade',  
    prevEffect  : 'fade',  
    helpers : {  
    title : {  
    type : 'inside'  
    },  
    overlay : {  
    css : {  
    'background-color' : '#eee'  
    }  
}  
}  
    });  
});
```

When I add the fade transition, the caption text is not used but it defaults to the title text (which I am using for something else). Kinda stumped as to why this is not working. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
$(".fancybox")  
.fancybox({  
openEffect  : 'fade',  
closeEffect : 'fade',  
nextEffect  : 'fade',  
prevEffect  : 'fade',  
helpers : {  
title : null  
overlay : {  
css : {  
'background-color' : '#4a4a4a'  
}  
}  
},  
beforeLoad: function() {  
this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');  
}  
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a new API option, then you need to separate each of them with a *comma* but the last.

You added `title : null` but forgot to add the trailing comma so that triggers a js error and the rest of the options won't work.

Actually you don't need that option at all since you are overriding the `title` content with the `caption` attribute inside the callback, so this code works just fine :

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    openEffect: 'fade',
    closeEffect: 'fade',
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade',
    helpers: {
        // title: null // you don't need this one
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background-color': '#4a4a4a'
            }
        }
    },
    beforeLoad: function () {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
});
```

Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qLZAP/)**